# Select elements does not reset properly

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

i am building an angular 4 application. there i have form witch include a select element in a box

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="designation">Designation</label>
   <select [class.red-border]="registerUser.controls.designation.invalid && registerUser.controls.designation.touched" formControlName="designation" class="form-control">
      <option   value="">Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let designation of designations"  value="{{designation}}">{{designation}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

i want to reset my form after user submits the form successfuly. But this select box does not get reset properly. it becomes empty once i reset the form. below is my code

component.ts formgroup

```
 registerUser = this.fb.group({
     name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     email: new FormControl('', [ 
            Validators.required,
            Validators.email,
            this.emailDomainValidator
        ]),
     emailp: new FormControl('',Validators.email),
     designation:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     empType:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     mobileNo:new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),   

  });
```

how i reset the form

```
submit_user = ():void=>{
     if(this.registerUser.valid){
           console.log("register user form submited")
           this.registerUser.reset();
       }
  }
```

why is it getting empty instead of going back to select

Comment: "why is it getting empty instead of going back to select" what it means?
What is currently happening and What output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.registerUser.reset({
    designation: ""
});
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#reset

---

Interestingly, because the "value is set to null". Setting the option value to null also works:

```
<select>
    <option value="null">Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reset-form)